# A query that shows the cost within $2 of the most expensive film

Tags: sql, oracle, max, aggregate-functions, oracle9i

```
TITLE   GEN DURATION    PRODUCTION_YEAR MED PURCHASE_PRICE  PURCHASE_   MOVIE_ID
```

those are my columns

I am using oracle 9i

Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: Please add sample data, expected outcome, and some logic to create the query and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MAX` function in sub-query in `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM MOVIE
 WHERE PURCHASE_PRICE >= (SELECT MAX(PURCHASE_PRICE) - 2 FROM MOVIE)
```

Answer (score 0):

[You know how to get the price of the most expensive movie](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65087237/146325). So just use that information to filter all the movies.

```
with exmv as 
  (select max(purchase_price) as mx_price 
   from movie)
select movie.*
from       movie 
cross join exmv
where movie.purchase_price >= exmv.mx_price - 2
;
```

This query puts the aggregate query in a subquery factoring clause which it references in the FROM clause. We use a CROSS JOIN because we know the subquery returns only one row, so we don't need any join criteria. The WHERE clause filters on the basis of price.

---

You say you are using Oracle 9i. Why such an old version? It's been out of Extended Support for a decade! Anyway, that's the version which introduced the WITH clause (and the ANSI-92 join syntax). It's in the documentation. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/statements_103a.htm#2065648)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with analytic functions, that are available in Oracle 9i:

```
select *
from (
    select m.*, max(purchase_price) over() as max_purchase_price
    from movie m
) m
where purchase_price >= max_purchase_price - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(PURCHASE_PRICE) over () as max_price
      from t
     ) t
where PURCHASE_PRICE >= max_price - 2;
```